# Apple silicon not able to read environment variable in gradle test

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit, spring-test, apple-silicon

I am using Apple silicon (M1 Processor) for developing sping-boot application.

My JVM is as below.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.52.0.23-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.52.0.23-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

And I am using `gradle-6.8.3-all.zip` version of Gradle.

Under `src/test/resources`, there is a property file named `application-test.properties` and it has variables as below.

```
test.environment.variable=${TEST_ENV}
```

My test code for reading this variable is as below.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class EnvironmentVariableReadTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Test
    public void environmentVariableReadTest() {
        String variable = testService.getEnvironmentVariableFromAutowiredComponent();
        assertNotNull(variable);
        System.out.println(variable + " is not null");
    }
}
```

- `TestService` and `TestComponent` is each described below.

```java
// TestService

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

    private final TestComponent testComponent;

    public String getEnvironmentVariableFromAutowiredComponent() {
        return testComponent.getEnvironmentVariable();
    }
}

// TestComponent

@Component
@Getter
public class TestComponent {

    @Value("${test.environment.variable}")
    private String environmentVariable;
}
```

I set the environment variable using the way on the screenshot below.

[image: How I added environment variable.]
As test result, I am getting the error below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testComponent': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'TEST_ENV' in value "${TEST_ENV}"
```

I asked JetBrains help center to resolve this issue, and the only answer I got is that this doesn't happen on their computer. I've checked that this test code works on windows and Linux.
Also, I have tried to clean-reinstall IntelliJ several times on this machine (Apple Silicon Macbook Pro).

Sample project can be reproduced at --> [Project Link](https://github.com/sangwoo-98/Intellij-Test)

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem. Unfortunately in my case, the solution was to use JDK via Rosetta 2 or upgrade Gradle to version 7.x.x.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30521890)

Comment: upgrade Gradle to 7.3 fixes the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Open the Gradle settings:

[image]

Change `Build and run using` and `Run and test using` to `Intellij Idea`.

[image]

Comment: With an Apple M2 chip and Gradle 8.1.1 version this was the only solution that worked for me